# Create Control from String Value

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am using DevExpress Components controls.I want to create controls from string Value

like "DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit".I know I can make this with reflection like

```
var textBoxType = typeof(Control).Assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox", true);
var textBox = Activator.CreateInstance(textBoxType);
```

I want to make this for write little code.but DevExpress have  a lot of namespace and class.
Can I create control from string unless give A MainClass? (like my sample code typeof(Control))
if I can not make I have to use  alot of if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know which assembly the class is defined in.

For example, all of the editors are in `DevExpress.XtraEditors.vX.Y.dll`, or `typeof(BaseEdit).Assembly`.

If you don't know which assembly it's defined in, you can create a collection of DevExpress assemblies (`typeof(GridControl).Assembly, typeof(TreeList).Assembly, ...`) and loop through them until `asm.GetType(name)` doesn't return `null`.
Note that it will be very slow.